# jQuery weekcalendar displays correctly in Firefox but not in Chrome/Safari (only on iOS/OSX devices)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, browser

**PROBLEM ONLY EXISTS ON MAC DEVICES.**

I am using [jQuery weekcalendar plugin](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) to show a webbased calendar with appointments. I am having a problem to display it in Chrome & Safari (maybe also others), but it displays correctly in Firefox.

Firefox *(the scrollbar is there even if no scrolling is enabled)*:
[image]

Chrome *(note that Chrome doesn't show the scrollbar when it is not needed. If user starts to scroll the calendar, the scrollbar is added to the green page content)*:
[image]

I don't know what code I should post. Please have a look at the page source code of my [calendar](http://www.slinder.ch/admin/admin/calendar/calendar.html).

Any hint is appreciated. Thx.

---

**Edit**:
I just found out that it only doesn't work on Mac devices (iPhone, iPad, Macbook Pro) with Safari and Chrome. The problem ist that on mac the scrollbar is not shown, whereas on Windows the scrollbar is shown in the calendar directly and it is static. On mac the scroll bar disappears when the page doesn't move. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: it displays correctly for me in Chrome.

Comment: So what you want is the scrollbar to be always visible? If so, are you aware that iOS doesn't have scrollbars?

Comment: Yes. But OSX does have scrollbars. But they are hidden as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing a scrollbar on webkit browsers for everyone* can be done by using a custom scrollbar. On your CSS, add this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

More customization options in:
http://davidwalsh.name/custom-scrollbars

--
*If you need only to see locally on your machine, follow this:
http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/03/show-scroll-bars-mac-os-x-lion/

Answer (score 4):

Which version of chrome and safari you are using? It displays correctly for me in chrome and safari. if you are using the concept of template in your code, then try deleting the browser cache.

Comment: Safrai 6.0.2 and Chrome 24.0.1312.52. It also doesn't show correctly on the iPad.

Comment: Browser cache has been removed, still same behavior as mentioned above.

Comment: sorry man. then no idea. while i was developing a calendar, i had this problem. in my case templates was the problem. since i wrote templates to load different views, it was cached by browser so i couldn't see the changes.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I found the problem but don't know how to fix it.